# Error adding two List<string> values to a object {get, internal set;}

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am trying to add the `List<string> container = new List<string>()` and `config.ContainerNames.Add(String.Join("\n",container));` to an object in another klass and replace the `return container;` with `return config.ListContainerData;`.

**ListContainer()**

```
public static List<string> ListContainer(StartConfig config)
{
    if (config != null || config.BlobClient != null)
    {
        config = Program.GetConfig();
    }
    if (config == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("config");
    }
    if (config.BlobClient == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("BlobClient must not be null", "config");
    }
    List<string> container = new List<string>();

    //Get the list of the blob from the above container
    IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = config.BlobClient.ListContainers();

    foreach (CloudBlobContainer item in containers)
    {
       config.ListContainerData.Add(container.Add(item.Name));

        config.ContainerNames.Add(String.Join("\n", container));
    }

    return container; //replace with config.ListContainerData;
}
```

Within my `foreach()` I am calling `config.ListContainerData.Add(container.Add(item.Name));` which is giving me an error for *cannot convert void into string*.

**StartConfig klass**

```
public class StartConfig
{
    public StartConfig()
    {
        ContainerNames = new List<string>();
    }

    public CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount { get; internal set; }
    public CloudBlobClient BlobClient { get; internal set; }
    public CloudBlobContainer Container { get; internal set; }

    public List<string> ContainerNames { get; internal set; }
    public List<string> ListContainerData { get; internal set; }       
}
```

I am also calling a method called `GetConfig()` which is instantiating the `StartConfig` klass. (i.e. `StartConfig config = new StartConfig();`) From my understanding I should simply be able to add both the `container` && `config.ContinerNames` to the `config.ListContainerData`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `List.Add()` method does not return the list itself. See the signature on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
public void Add(
    T item
)
```

Thus by calling `config.ListContainerData.Add(container.Add(item.Name));` you are effectively adding `void`, not a `List<string>` as expected.

Split the call and either add the container or the new item depending on what you are trying to achieve (assumption here under):

```
ListContainerData = container;
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! However I am now getting an error of *Cannot assign void to implicitly-typed variable* for `var subItem = container.Add(item.Name);`

Comment: Yes, I removed that, I made the same error you did. This is BS. What should ListContainerData contain?

Comment: It should contain, `container` and `config.ContainerNames`

Comment: `ListContainerData` is a `List<string>, thus by calling `Add()`, you are adding a `string`, not a `List<string>`. If you want `ListContainerData` to contain the elements of your `container` (which is also a `List<string>`), you either change the reference via `ListContainerData = container`, or copy the items from one collection to the other.